# Laravel 5.7 change verification mail sender

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, email-verification

Currently, when a Laravel user verification mail is sent, the sender is `hello@example.com` with a name of `Example`. How can I modify these values without changing files in the vendor directory (e.g. `php artisan vendor:publish`, but what?). I´ve looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416804/how-to-customize-the-email-verification-email-from-laravel-5-7), `\Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail.php` and `\Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail.php`, but while a markdown template is declared (which I´ve published to my resources to tweak it a little), there´s no code which actually sends the mail with sender and sender name!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found in `config/mail.php`, see the snippet:

```
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
```

Add the values to your `.env` file and it should be good.