# Laravel verify e-mail preview, render verification email

Tags: php, laravel

For a laravel project I want to view how the verify email, email looks.
I did run `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail` and in the documentation I found:

> Sometimes you may wish to capture the HTML content of a mailable
> without sending it. To accomplish this, you may call the render method
> of the mailable. This method will return the evaluated contents of the
> mailable as a string:
>
> `$invoice = App\Invoice::find(1);`
>
> `return (new App\Mail\InvoicePaid($invoice))->render();`

Is it possible to do something like this for the confirm email, email? I sarched for Mailable in my project but got no results. Is ther another way to view the email without sending it?

Comment: Do you have a mailable class setup yet?

Comment: @Abiola No im using all default laravel settings.

Comment: I'd suggest you go through this [article](https://johnbeales.com/2018/browser-preview-laravel-password-reset-and-verification-emails/). It should help.

Comment: Solving it with a route is quite dirty, if I were you, I would install [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope) and set your mail driver to `log`. You can then inspect all emails. And install Telescope using `--dev`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1 - Preview in Browser**

Add a new route, preferably just in a test set up, that goes like this:

```
Route::get( '/verify-test', function () {
    // Get a user for demo purposes
    $user = App\User::find(1);
    return (new Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail())->toMail($user);
}
```

In my tests with laravel 7 this was enough. I didn't have to publish any notifications. It just rendered nicely in the browser! Of course, if you want to also change the content of the notification it's a good idea to do:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

The content of the notification is in the file `resources/views/vendor/notifications`

[Laravel Notification Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#previewing-mail-notifications)

**Option 2 - Catch the Mails**

What you can always do is either set a mailtrap.io account as smtp server and view the mail there or use the "Universal To" as described in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#mail-and-local-development):

```
// config/mail.php
'to' => [
    'address' => 'example@example.com',
    'name' => 'Example'
],
```

Comment: funny how hard you're trying

Comment: I know, SO is like a current addiction :D But I'm also genuinly interested and came up with my own solution by studying the source code, reading the docs and testing ;)

Comment: @wschopohl Very nice thats exactly what I was looking for. The files in notifications seem to be templates for the notifications message but as far as I can tell I can not change the content of the email verifcation email in the file.

Comment: Interesting. After publishing I could change that notification and instantly saw the changes in the test view route..

Comment: @wschopohl  which file do you change? Im only see "resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php"

Comment: that's exactly the only one I'm seeing, too. I was able to alter the text down by "Subcopy". I think the rest of the message is defined directly in "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php" which in turn seems to utilize the Lang Facade.. Can't dig deeper now, because the bed is calling ;)

Comment: I think the rabbit hole goes something like "VerifyEmail" uses a new "MailMessage" which extends "SimpleMessage" which has functions like line(...) to throw text into..

Comment: This seems promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416804/how-to-customize-the-email-verification-email-from-laravel-5-7  or google laravel custom verification email

Answer (score 1):

To be honest? Yes you can add routes and make them accessible locally only, but why the hassle.

Laravel already built a tool called [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope). Just install with composer, add `--dev` for development only and be done with it. Set your mail driver to `log` and inspect without the need to hack around with routes or whatever.

If you wish to test the mail without the hassle of registering all the time, create a factory to generate and mock emails and use [Tinker](https://github.com/laravel/tinker), or better [Tinkerwell](https://tinkerwell.app) to speedup your development process.