# Changing the default “From” field of email in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I send an email with my app from laravel, the receiver gets email from:

**Example <hello@example.com>**

How can I customize this?

I was able to customize the default Subject field as the answer posted in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415107/5016573

I am using mailgun as mail server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.env` file contains two attributes related to what you are asking:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=johndoe@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Doe"
```

These attributes are then used at `config/mail.php`.

Comment: What if I want to use different email addresses depending on the relatedness of the form. For example, I want to use `donotreply@domain.com` for my contact form. Then I want to use `myemail@domain.com` for my registration form. How can I implement this?